# My App not posting data to a MySQL database on android

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, eclipse

My App can't post data to a MySQL database on Android.

The App is not responding because I add this line of code.

```
//StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
//StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

It crashes without this line of code.

Here's my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testingtesting;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    Button b;
    InputStream is = null;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = "" +et1.getText().toString();
                String age = "" +et2.getText().toString();
                String email = "" +et3.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", age));
                list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/testing.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();
                    String msg = "Data Entered Succesfully";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                    Log.e("ClientProtocol", "Log_tag");
                }catch(IOException e){
                    Log.e("Log_tag", "IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testingtesting.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:hint="Age"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testingtesting"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**testing.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db("newdb", $con);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

mysql_query("insert into mytable(name, age, email) values('{$name}','{$age}','{$email}')");
//mysql_close();
?>
```

LogCat without

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

09-15 09:51:04.629: D/dalvikvm(870): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-15 09:51:05.628: E/Trace(870): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-15 09:51:06.998: D/gralloc_goldfish(870): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-15 09:51:07.098: D/dalvikvm(870): GC_CONCURRENT freed 137K, 4% free 4352K/4516K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 198ms
09-15 09:53:27.838: I/Choreographer(870): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-15 09:53:37.089: I/Choreographer(870): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-15 09:53:38.789: D/AndroidRuntime(870): Shutting down VM
09-15 09:53:38.789: W/dalvikvm(870): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2bd39930)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.example.testingtesting.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-15 09:53:38.828: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did u executed ur service in broswer?is it working?

Comment: The App just freezes. Not valuable information in the logcat

Comment: app freezes since u not using Asynstask..

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would like you to share me a tutorial on how to implement the AsyncTask.

Comment: refer this answer -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474317/trouble-with-http-get/25474331#25474331

Comment: Welcome and do check ur php on broswer i think it will not work change $_POST to $_REQUEST so that u can check in broswer as well with get method

Comment: Thanks I used AsyncTask and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore JSON, use json_encode in php, As well as try Using AsyncTask or better yet move to the Google Android Volley Library to stay with the latest / fastest reliable networking calls.

Comment: I'm new to Android and Java, I don't know how to make a JSON call in php

Comment: Well it will be complicated at start. But it is easy to learn android volley. Your only problem would be the PHP Web API for json, it'll take time / code practice to learn.

Comment: Can you share a tutorial that can help me kickstart it. Thanks

Comment: try this for volley / json http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

I can't seem to find any easy php api to json tutorial but this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

use **Asynctask** for network calls. you won't be able to do any network task if your targetsdkversion is greater than 10. you must strictly use asynctask for android 3.x or after that.

and you still want to run this app than lower your android:targetSdkVersion to 10 or 9 than i might think it will work. but i suggest you to switch over asynctask.

for more visit : http://aiyazparmar.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-post-http-request-to-server-in.html